# CSVHelper not mapping the properites correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, csvhelper

I am trying to write an array of objects to a csv in mvc4 using csvHelper.
My Controller code looks like this

```
public FileResult ExportAudits()
{
   var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
   var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
   var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter);
   UserAudit[] audits = auditDal.GetUserAudits().ToArray<UserAudit>();
   csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<UserAuditMap>();
   csvWriter.WriteRecords(audits);
   streamWriter.Flush();
   memoryStream.Position = 0;
   return File(memoryStream, "text/csv", "Changes.csv");
}
```

My Mapping class looks like this

```
public sealed class UserAuditMap : CsvClassMap<UserAudit>
{
    public UserAuditMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Action);
        Map(m => m.ActionDetail);
        Map(m => m.UserProfile.FirstName);
    }
}
```

The problem i am having when i open the csv file is, only the header has the Action, ActionDetail and FirstName, but the data rows still has all the values. It looks like the Mapper has no effect. The class I am passing to the csvHelper is not the actual entity UserAudit but the Dynamic Proxy of the entity. That does seems to have an effect. My question is how to map the Dynamic proxy entity correctly.

[image: I have an example below of expected vs actual value]

Comment: Can you give an example of your expected output and your actual output?

Comment: I have edited the question with your answers

Comment: I ended up creating an anonymous object with desired columns and not use the mapper overall which will work.